# Force user to set metadata when publishing a site page

Tags: metadata

Using Sharepoint Online with modern pages.
I've created a required custom metadata field, which I can see in the library is not set for any site page (I'm not saving documents in this site, just pages).
When I edit and publish a site page, I'm not prompted to set this metadata. 
Is there a way to force a user to set the metadata when the page is published?